# Is it possible to rearrange my Google Analytics profiles and accounts?

Tags: google-analytics

Some months ago, I registered profile X, Y, Z under account A in Google Analytics.

But I hope to move profile X to account B and let the Y, Z remained in account A. Is it possible to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do that (yet). I'm saying "yet", because Google is always changing, so maybe you will be able to one day.